# Trans File use java socket, ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream but blocked

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, objectinputstream

Send file with socket BIO use Socket, ServerSocket, ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream but blocked. The detail code is:
Model:

```
@Data
@ToString
public class FileTransModel implements Serializable {
    private String fileName;
    private Long fileLength;
    private Integer status;
}
```

Client:

```
public class FileTransClient {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
    
    private static final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1888);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
            
            File file = new File("D:\\trans\\1.mp4");
            FileTransModel fileTransModel = new FileTransModel();
            fileTransModel.setFileName(file.getName());
            fileTransModel.setFileLength(file.length());
            oos.writeObject(fileTransModel);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
            int len;
            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(BUFFER)) != -1) {
                System.out.println(len);
                oos.write(BUFFER, 0, len);
                oos.flush();
            }
            System.out.println("file send over");
            FileTransModel model = (FileTransModel) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(model);
            
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class FileTransServer {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;

    private static final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1888);
            System.out.println("Socket Server start on port: 1888");
            while(true) {
                Socket accept = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("new file come!");
                new Thread(new Task(accept)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    private static class Task implements Runnable {

        Socket socket;
        
        public Task(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                FileTransModel fileTransModel = (FileTransModel) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(fileTransModel);
                
                File file = new File("D:\\trans_rec2\\"+fileTransModel.getFileName());
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                int len;
                len = ois.read(BUFFER);
                int size = 0;
                while (true) {
                    size += len;
                    System.out.println(len + ": " + size);
                    if (len == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    bufferedOutputStream.write(BUFFER, 0, len);
                    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                    len = ois.read(BUFFER);
                }
                System.out.println("file write over");
                
                fileTransModel.setStatus(0);
                
                oos.writeObject(fileTransModel);
                System.out.println("file receive over");
                
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the result is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMxIw.png)
Client had trans over, but Server is like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjx7E.png)
it cannot go on. how to fix it

I have tried to use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream, but the result is the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of `read` method in `ObjectInputStream`:

> This method will block until some input is available.

So basically you are never getting `len` to be equal to `-1` at server side. That's because of the sequence of events:

1. Client sends the model and then the file bytes. Client then *waits* to receive model from server. `ObjectInputStream` is in blocking I/O mode here, so is `readObject` in the following snippet of your client side code:

   ```
   System.out.println("file send over");
   FileTransModel model = (FileTransModel) ois.readObject(); // Blocks here.
   ```
2. Server receives the model. Then server receives buffers of *a positive size* until the other end is closed.
3. But client is waiting for the model to be received, so it's not going to close.
4. Since server is *waiting blocked for more bytes or a `-1`* (assuming no `IOException` occurs) inside the loop, then it is not going to send the model back.

As a result both sides are blocked waiting from each other.

To solve this you can signify the end of file transmission in a way such that the server knows when to stop reading file bytes. Since the file contents can be arbitrary and its size is not pre-determined at server side, then you can send the file size *before* you begin sending its contents to the server. But the model already has this information, so your reading loop in the server side can be modified from:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

int len;
len = ois.read(BUFFER);
int size = 0;
while (true) {
    size += len;
    System.out.println(len + ": " + size);
    if (len == -1) {
        break;
    }
    bufferedOutputStream.write(BUFFER, 0, len);
    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
    len = ois.read(BUFFER);
}
```

to:

```
try (final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
     final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {
    final long expected = fileTransModel.getFileLength() == null? 0: fileTransModel.getFileLength();
    long size = 0;
    while (size < expected) {
        final int current = ois.read(BUFFER);
        bufferedOutputStream.write(BUFFER, 0, current);
        //bufferedOutputStream.flush(); //Flushing after each write would defeat the purpose of buffering, so better don't do it.
        size += current;
        System.out.println("So far: " + size);
    }
} //Always close the file.
```

Closing the client side `ObjectOutputStream` (the `oos` reference) right after writing the file contents, in order for example to get a `-1` at the server side, is not an option here since closing `oos` would close the underlying `OutputStream` of the `Socket`, which in turn according to the documentation would close the `Socket` itself. So then if you were going to send the model back (ie from server to client), then a `SocketException` would be raised (the `Socket` would be no more usable).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and I also have a doubt that Server get the fileLength is 10 and will receive 10 file bytes, but some bytes are lost during transmission, Server only receive 8 bytes. will this happen? if will, how to break the while loop and throw Exceptions.

Comment: `Socket`s in Java [work with TCP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/package-summary.html#sockets-heading). Mitigating loss of data during transmission is the responsibility of the TCP protocol implementation to guarantee (eg via retransmission). As far as I know, if an error occurs at the TCP level, then an exception will be thrown (although I can't find a reference for that right now sadly). So you get all bytes if and only if no exceptions occur (ie the mechanism you describe is already in place, you just need to handle the exceptions).

Comment: So it is, I understand, thank you so much!